# parsing in sybase a fields with different digits

Tags: sybase

i have a field on sybase for a particular table where i need to select only the first value. See the example below:

```
Field1
104676;ABC;345776;TEST
2332;ABC;345776;TEST
8765432;ABC;345776;TEST
```

This particular field have char format. I want to pullout only the first value (starting from the left) that is compost by different number of digits, in particular:

```
Field1
104676
2332
8765432
```

in conclusion i need to formart the field in numeric and pullout only the first value.
thanks id advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you may easily pull this using SUBSTRING/CHARINDEX function combination -

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Field1, 1, CHARINDEX(';', Field1) -1)
FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

Comment: If now I have the value with number + ; how can I remove the ; ?